# Commonwealth Saga: What is the motive behind that part of the plan?

Tags: commonwealth-saga

I recently finished reading (again) the Commonwealth Saga, by Peter F. Hamilton, and something struck me near the conclusion of everything:

> **Tarlo** the Policeman and traitor, after destroying the portal to Half-Way, says roughly something about *Qatux the Raiel being already on the way to Far-Away.* This shocks **Vic Russel**, loyal Policeman, who asks **Tarlo** how could he know that.

Why is it part of the plan of the

> **Starflyer** to bring the Raiel to Far-Away,

and why is it so important that it happens?

Comment: Before I write an answer: have you read any of the other books in the universe?

Comment: @user3482749 I did not, but having paid attention to the bibliography for once, it's most definitely planned

Comment: That makes this very hard to answer, honestly. Any objections to me going all Brandon Sanderson and saying "read and find out"?

Comment: Given the OP has completed the Commonwealth Saga it doesn't seem unrealistic that plot points can/should be resolved within the trilogy. While more depth may be added to the role of the Raiel, their relevance to the Starflayer if not explained in the Saga itself would be reasonably pointed to as a plot hole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Commonwealth forms the basis for a Universe rather than being self-contained within the original trilogy. [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/series/108563-commonwealth-universe) shows a total of seven and a half books at the moment. The most recent printed in 2016.

The Raiel feature more prominently in the later books, so I've tagged the below as a spoiler, but I think this information, quoted from the [wiki](https://peterfhamilton.fandom.com/wiki/Raiel), is implied in the original trilogy if not outright stated.

> The Raiel are extremely advanced, both technologically and evolutionarily. They are the originators of the Dark Fortress technology used by the Anomine to imprison the Primes, as well as sentient arkships like the High Angel

Comment: I think that was more implied than stated, but it does make way more sense now. I think I spoiled myself just a little, but it gave me the motivation to order the other books of the universe and keep going !